# I want to search and display the information of a “contact” but it doesn’t work

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

So I have a file (that is an address book) that contains informations about people formatted this way

————————-CONTACT————————-

First Name : Tony

Last Name : Stark

Address : Malibu

Phone number : 10203044032

E-mail : tony.stark@jarvis.com

Company / Place of work : Stark Industries

————————-CONTACT————————-

I have this code :

```
#define MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS 1000

int main()
{

 long pos = 0; /// this will store the position of the cursor  
 char address_book_content[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS];
 char contact_name[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS];
 char *string_exists = NULL;
 File *show_address_book = NULL;
 show_address_book = fopen("addressBook.txt", "r");

 printf("Enter the name of the contact you want to search");
 scanf("%s", &contact_name);

 /** I want : when the user inputs a name, the program searches it in the file and if it’s found it prints the rest of the file starting from the line where that name is. So I tried the following **/

 while ( (fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book) != NULL)
 {

  if ( (string_exists = strstr(address_book_content, contact_name) != NULL)
  {

   printf("%s", address_book_content);
   pos = ftell(show_address_book);
   fseek(show_address_book, 27, pos); /// 27 in just a random number, I just want it to change the position of the cursor in the file
   printf("%s", address_book_content);

  }

 }

 return 0;

}
```

When I input “Tony” for example it only displays :

First Name : Tony

I want it to display the whole information for the contact “Tony”

So if you could help me, thanks

Comment: Don't use a word-processor to code, the double-quotes for the strings are all wrong.

Comment: I don’t actually get well what you are saying, could you explain more please?

Comment: @TonyStark why did you cancel my edition ?

Comment: @TonyStark You might have copy&pasted your code in a word processor or similar program, because it changed the capitalization and the double-quotes so the current code won't compile.

Comment: that time it is useless to compile to see the problem ^^

Comment: Oh I got it right now, I just re-typed the code which is on my computer using my iPhone. O edited it thanks

Comment: @bruno I did not cancel it, I think that we were editing at the same time, cause just after I saw the first comment talking about the double quotes I started editing it

Comment: OT: always check the returned value from C library functions, looking for an error event.  Regarding: `fseek(show_address_book, 27, pos);`  the third parameter is from a small set: `SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END`  NOT some random integer 'pos'

Comment: If the posted code does not compile, then how are we to reproduce the problem and then help you to debug it?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: OT: a single space for each indent level is not sufficient.  With a variable width font, a single space will (effectively) disappear.  Suggest using the '{}' format button or set each indent level to 4 spaces

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files!  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code actually includes (or is your code actually missing the needed `#include` statements?)

Comment: OT: regarding: `long pos = 0; /// this will store the position of the cursor`  This is NOT storing the position of the cursor.  Rather it is (at best) storing the current location in the file of the 'file pointer', which is a concept of where in the file the next read/write operation will occur, and not an actual pointer

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", &contact_name);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful (in this case, anything other than '1' is an error) 2) when using the input format specifiers:'%s' and/or '%[...]' always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also removes any possibility of the user overrunning the input buffer and avoids any possible undefined behavior

Comment: because of the way the input file is formatted. the `First Name : Tony` is all that is in the input buffer. so the code must make repeated calls to `fgets()` to input the other lines of the `contact'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
printf(“%s”, address_book_content);
pos = ftell(show_address_book);
fseek(show_address_book, 27, pos); /// 27 in just a random number, I just want it to change the position of the cursor in the file
printf(“%s”, address_book_content);
```

the *fseek* doesn't change `address_book_content` so you write two times the same thing

you need to read in your file from the position you computed to be able to write what you read, modifying `address_book_content` is you still print it. Or just read & print the next lines after the one you read :

```
while ( (fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book) != NULL)
 {
  if ( (string_exists = strstr(address_book_content, contact_name) != NULL)
  {
    fputs(address_book_content, stdout); /* fputs rather printf to not write again a \n */
    /* supposing it was the firstname there are 5 lines after to read and print */
    fputs(fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book), stdout);
    fputs(fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book), stdout);
    fputs(fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book), stdout);
    fputs(fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book), stdout);
    fputs(fgets(address_book_content, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, show_address_book), stdout);
    break;
  }
}
```

**Warning *strstr* is not the right way because it will catch name containing the expected one, for instance the name *IamNotTonyAtAll* match *Tony* using *strstr***

Of course this is quite very expensive to read each time the file to search for a name ...

---

A full proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS 1000

int main()
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("addressBook.txt", "r");

  if (fp == NULL) 
    puts("cannot read addressBook.txt");
  else {
    /* use static vars to not take place into the stack */
    static char contact_name[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS];
    printf("Enter the name of the contact you want to search : ");

    if (scanf("%s", contact_name) != 1)
      puts("invalid input");
    else {
      static char line1[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS];
      static char line2[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS];

       /* to have \n at the end like the read lines, it is also possible
          to read the name with fgets but in case of extra spaces at the end it is not found */
      strcat(contact_name, "\n");

      while ((fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp) != NULL) &&
             (fgets(line2, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp) != NULL))
      {
        if ((strcmp(line1 + /*bypass "First Name : "*/ 13, contact_name) == 0) || /* first name */
            (strcmp(line2 + /*bypass "Last Name : "*/ 12, contact_name) == 0)) { /* last name */
          /* that one */
          fputs(line1, stdout);
          fputs(line2, stdout);
          if (fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp) != NULL) {
            fputs(line1, stdout);
            if (fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp) != NULL) {
              fputs(line1, stdout);
              if (fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp) != NULL) {
                fputs(line1, stdout);
                if (fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp) != NULL) {
                  fputs(line1, stdout);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          break;
        }
        else {
          fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp);
          fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp);
          fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp);
          fgets(line1, MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS, fp);
        }
      }
      fclose(fp);
    }
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Examples :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the name of the contact you want to search : Tony
First Name : Tony
Last Name : Stark
Address : Malibu
Phone number : 10203044032
E-mail : tony.stark@jarvis.com
Company / Place of work : Stark Industries
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the name of the contact you want to search : Stark
First Name : Tony
Last Name : Stark
Address : Malibu
Phone number : 10203044032
E-mail : tony.stark@jarvis.com
Company / Place of work : Stark Industries
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the name of the contact you want to search : Bruno
First Name : Bruno
Last Name : Pages
Address : somewhere in France
Phone number : 123456789
E-mail : me@hiddenAddress.fr
Company / Place of work : BoUML unlimited
```

Supposing *addressBook.txt* contains :

```
First Name : Tony
Last Name : Stark
Address : Malibu
Phone number : 10203044032
E-mail : tony.stark@jarvis.com
Company / Place of work : Stark Industries
First Name : Bruno
Last Name : Pages
Address : somewhere in France
Phone number : 123456789
E-mail : me@hiddenAddress.fr
Company / Place of work : BoUML unlimited
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I noticed that it is printed 2 times, I don’t understand why the position of the cursor is not changed

Comment: @TonyStark you can use any cursor position, `address_book_content` doesn't depend on the cursor position, you need to read again in your file

Comment: Oh okay I got it right now, thanks. But how do I avoid to always read the file before printing it (if it is possible) cause I want the program to automatically display the rest of the file

Comment: @TonyStark if you need to search for only *one* name it is ok, else you need to read and memorize the file, and in that case you need to make a kind od dictionary where the keys are the names and the value the full multi lines to print

Comment: Yes, i want to search for only one name.

Comment: @TonyStark in that case it is ok ... except the strstr

Comment: So you mean i have to remove the "strstr" ? How should i proceed then ? Because as you said it's very expensive and not really common to read the file that much time

Comment: I'll keep seaching, but if theres any other solution i think that i will use that one. Thanks @bruno

Comment: @TonyStark I edited my answer to add a full working proposal

Comment: Thanks for all @bruno, i tested it it's now working as i excepted. And i re-tested the first code with the "strstr" too, and if i type something that is not in the file (a random string) or just "IamNotTonyAtAll" it still works (I mean the file is not displayed), to go further handling that i added a message saying "this contact doesn't exist" if you type some《n'importe quoi》. Thank you

Comment: @TonyStark to know if you found or not the name just add a `int found = 0;` before the while and set it to 1 when found, then test the value after the while and that's all

Comment: Okay i got it, thanks. If you want too, i can send you the project to test it and tell me if there are some things to improve of some

Comment: OT:  regarding: `puts("cannot read addressBook.txt");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` performs all that correctly when the error is from a C library function.  Other wise use: `fprintf( stderr, "your error message\n" );`